# How to aggregate values into collection after groupBy?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with schema as such:

```
[visitorId: string, trackingIds: array<string>, emailIds: array<string>]
```

Looking for a way to group (or maybe rollup?) this dataframe by visitorid where the trackingIds and emailIds columns would append together.  So for example if my initial df looks like:

```
visitorId   |trackingIds|emailIds
+-----------+------------+--------
|a158|      [666b]      |    [12]
|7g21|      [c0b5]      |    [45]
|7g21|      [c0b4]      |    [87]
|a158|      [666b, 777c]|    []
```

I would like my output df to look like this

```
visitorId   |trackingIds|emailIds
+-----------+------------+--------
|a158|      [666b,666b,777c]|      [12,'']
|7g21|      [c0b5,c0b4]     |      [45, 87]
```

Attempting to use `groupBy` and `agg` operators but not have much luck.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.4**

You can replace `flatten` `udf` with built-in [`flatten` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@flatten(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.flatten
```

leaving the rest as-is.

**Spark >= 2.0, < 2.4**

It is possible but quite expensive. Using data you've provided:

```
case class Record(
    visitorId: String, trackingIds: Array[String], emailIds: Array[String])

val df = Seq(
  Record("a158", Array("666b"), Array("12")),
  Record("7g21", Array("c0b5"), Array("45")),
  Record("7g21", Array("c0b4"), Array("87")),
  Record("a158", Array("666b",  "777c"), Array.empty[String])).toDF
```

and a helper function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val flatten = udf((xs: Seq[Seq[String]]) => xs.flatten)
```

we can fill the blanks with placeholders:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, lit, when}

val dfWithPlaceholders = df.withColumn(
  "emailIds", 
  when(size($"emailIds") === 0, array(lit(""))).otherwise($"emailIds"))
```

`collect_lists` and `flatten`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, collect_list}

val emailIds = flatten(collect_list($"emailIds")).alias("emailIds")
val trackingIds = flatten(collect_list($"trackingIds")).alias("trackingIds")

df
  .groupBy($"visitorId")
  .agg(trackingIds, emailIds)

// +---------+------------------+--------+
// |visitorId|       trackingIds|emailIds|
// +---------+------------------+--------+
// |     a158|[666b, 666b, 777c]|  [12, ]|
// |     7g21|      [c0b5, c0b4]|[45, 87]|
// +---------+------------------+--------+
```

With statically typed `Dataset`:

```
df.as[Record]
  .groupByKey(_.visitorId)
  .mapGroups { case (key, vs) => 
    vs.map(v => (v.trackingIds, v.emailIds)).toArray.unzip match {
      case (trackingIds, emailIds) => 
        Record(key, trackingIds.flatten, emailIds.flatten)
  }}

// +---------+------------------+--------+
// |visitorId|       trackingIds|emailIds|
// +---------+------------------+--------+
// |     a158|[666b, 666b, 777c]|  [12, ]|
// |     7g21|      [c0b5, c0b4]|[45, 87]|
// +---------+------------------+--------+
```

**Spark 1.x**

You can convert to RDD and group

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

dfWithPlaceholders.rdd
  .map {
     case Row(id: String, 
       trcks: Seq[String @ unchecked],
       emails: Seq[String @ unchecked]) => (id, (trcks, emails))
  }
  .groupByKey
  .map {case (key, vs) => vs.toArray.unzip match {
    case (trackingIds, emailIds) => 
      Record(key, trackingIds.flatten, emailIds.flatten)
  }}
  .toDF

// +---------+------------------+--------+
// |visitorId|       trackingIds|emailIds|
// +---------+------------------+--------+
// |     7g21|      [c0b5, c0b4]|[45, 87]|
// |     a158|[666b, 666b, 777c]|  [12, ]|
// +---------+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: What if we have to remove duplicates in `trackingIds`?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the statically typed example can also be done with reduceGroups instead of mapGroups (and will require a subsequent map as well to get the result into the desired format). The docs for mapGroups seem to imply that reduce may be more efficient ("If an application intends to perform an aggregation over each key, it is best to use the reduce function or an Aggregator").

Comment: @rationull Your observation seems to be valid, but it would apply to the case, where aggregate function operates in constant memory. Here, where `size(f(x, y)) = size(x) + size(y)`, the cost of aggregation (and repeated copying of data) will significantly outweigh benefits of map-side reduction, in almost all cases.

Comment: @puru [Spark SQL: using collect_set over array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54616498/6910411)

Comment: @zero323 implementing a flatten udf for Spark >= 2.0, < 2.4 .. why do you say that it'll be quite expensive?

Answer (score 29):

@zero323's answer is *pretty* much complete, but Spark gives us even more flexibility. How about the following solution?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
inventory
  .select($"*", explode($"trackingIds") as "tracking_id")
  .select($"*", explode($"emailIds") as "email_id")
  .groupBy("visitorId")
  .agg(
    collect_list("tracking_id") as "trackingIds",
    collect_list("email_id") as "emailIds")
```

That however leaves out all empty collections (so there's some room for improvement :))

Comment: In this solution, is it possible to apply a orderBy() after the groupBy and before the agg()? Or in this situation orderBy will be non-deterministic?

Comment: In my opinion you answer it is not novel for the follow reasons
a)explode is deprecated in spark.2.2 . b) collect_list on a very large dataset can crash the driver process with OutOfMemoryError

Comment: @xXxpRoGrAmmErxXx Please don't get confused with `explode` operator and `explode` function. For b) possibly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use User defined aggregated functions.

1) create a custom UDAF using the scala class called customAggregation.

```
package com.package.name

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{MutableAggregationBuffer, UserDefinedAggregateFunction}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

class CustomAggregation() extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

// Input Data Type Schema
def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(StructField("col5", ArrayType(StringType))))

// Intermediate Schema
def bufferSchema = StructType(Array(
StructField("col5_collapsed",  ArrayType(StringType))))

// Returned Data Type .
def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(StringType)

// Self-explaining
def deterministic = true

// This function is called whenever key changes
def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
buffer(0) = Array.empty[String] // initialize array
}

// Iterate over each entry of a group
def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
buffer(0) =
  if(!input.isNullAt(0))
    buffer.getList[String](0).toArray ++ input.getList[String](0).toArray
  else
    buffer.getList[String](0).toArray
}

  // Merge two partial aggregates
 def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
 buffer1(0) = buffer1.getList[String](0).toArray ++ buffer2.getList[String](0).toArray
}

 // Called after all the entries are exhausted.
 def evaluate(buffer: Row) = {
  buffer.getList[String](0).asScala.toList.distinct
 }
}
```

2) Then use the UDAF in your code as

```
//define UDAF
val CustomAggregation = new CustomAggregation()
DataFrame
    .groupBy(col1,col2,col3)
    .agg(CustomAggregation(DataFrame(col5))).show()
```

Comment: You should __really__ avoid `UserDefinedAggregateFunctions` with complex buffers.

Comment: @hi-zir why so?

Comment: @hi-zir I have  built a UDAF with a Scala case class in the buffer. I won't say it is very performant, but since I used this in a NLP pipeline, the aggregation processing costs were ~2 orders of magnitude lower than the costs for document parsing. So depending on your application, a UDAF, while slow, might be just fine.