# how to concat the same column value to a new column with comma delimiters in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The format of input data as follows:

```
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|           date     |       user  |           product  |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|        2016-10-01  |        Tom  |           computer |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|        2016-10-01  |        Tom  |           iphone   |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|        2016-10-01  |       Jhon  |             book   |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|        2016-10-02  |        Tom  |             pen    |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|        2016-10-02  |       Jhon  |             milk   |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

And the format of output as follows:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+
|     user  |        products       |
+-----------------------------------+
|     Tom   |   computer,iphone,pen |
+-----------------------------------+
|     Jhon  |          book,milk    |  
+-----------------------------------+
```

The output shows all products every user bought order by date.

I want to process these data using Spark, who Can you help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Dataframe groupby with agg performing list appending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202997/spark-dataframe-groupby-with-agg-performing-list-appending)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate columns in apache spark dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450846/concatenate-columns-in-apache-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use map-reduceBykey() combination rather than groupBy.. Also assuming the data doesn't have the

```
#Read the data using val ordersRDD = sc.textFile("/file/path")
val ordersRDD = sc.parallelize( List(("2016-10-01","Tom","computer"), 
    ("2016-10-01","Tom","iphone"), 
    ("2016-10-01","Jhon","book"), 
    ("2016-10-02","Tom","pen"), 
    ("2016-10-02","Jhon","milk")))

#group by (date, user), sort by key & reduce by user & concatenate products
val dtusrGrpRDD = ordersRDD.map(rec => ((rec._2, rec._1), rec._3))
   .sortByKey().map(x=>(x._1._1, x._2))
   .reduceByKey((acc, v) => acc+","+v)

#if needed, make it to DF
scala> dtusrGrpRDD.toDF("user", "product").show()
+----+-------------------+
|user|            product|
+----+-------------------+
| Tom|computer,iphone,pen|
|Jhon|          book,milk|
+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: which version is your Spark, please?  Here has a error: cannot resolve symbol sortByKey.

Comment: Using DataFrames instead of RDDs is generally preferred since you can let the execution engine take care of deciding the optimal execution plan, and it will automatically apply various optimizations (predicate push-down, code generation, etc).  https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a HiveContext (which you should be):

Example using python:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set

df = ... load your df ...
new_df = df.groupBy("user").agg(collect_set("product").alias("products"))
```

If you don't want the resulting list in products deduped, you can use collect_list instead.

Answer (score 0):

For dataframes it is two-liner:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list
//collect_set nistead of collect_list if you don't want duplicates
val output =  join.groupBy("user").agg(collect_list($"product"))
```

GroupBy will give you a grouped user set post which you can iterate and collect_list or collect_set on the grouped dataset.