# Spark convert single column into array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I convert a single column in spark 2.0.1 into an array?

```
+---+-----+
| id| dist| 
+---+-----+
|1.0|2.0|
|2.0|4.0|
|3.0|6.0|
|4.0|8.0|
+---+-----+
```

should return `Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)`

A

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._ 
df.select("id").collectAsList.asScala.toArray
```

fails with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported array type: [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Row;
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported array type: [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Row;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Dataframe groupby with agg performing list appending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202997/spark-dataframe-groupby-with-agg-performing-list-appending)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you use JavaConverters if you then re-transform the Java List to a Scala List ? You just need to collect the dataset and then map this array of Rows to an array of doubles, like this :

```
df.select("id").collect.map(_.getDouble(0))
```

Comment: `collect()` on dataframe is not a scalable way.

Comment: Who talked about scalability here ?

Answer (score 6):

I'd try something like this with [dataframe aggregate function - collect_list()](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L201) to avoid memory overhead on the driver JVM. With this approach **only selected column values will be copied to driver JVM**.

```
df.select(collect_list("id")).first().getList[Double](0)
```

This returns `java.util.List[Double]`.