# spark aggregating column into Set efficiently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

How can I aggregate a column into an Set (Array of unique elements) in spark efficiently?

```
case class Foo(a:String, b:String, c:Int, d:Array[String])

  val df = Seq(Foo("A", "A", 123, Array("A")),
    Foo("A", "A", 123, Array("B")),
    Foo("B", "B", 123, Array("C", "A")),
    Foo("B", "B", 123, Array("C", "E", "A")),
    Foo("B", "B", 123, Array("D"))
  ).toDS()
```

Will result in

```
+---+---+---+---------+
|  a|  b|  c|        d|
+---+---+---+---------+
|  A|  A|123|      [A]|
|  A|  A|123|      [B]|
|  B|  B|123|   [C, A]|
|  B|  B|123|[C, E, A]|
|  B|  B|123|      [D]|
+---+---+---+---------+
```

what I am Looking for is (ordering of d column is not important):

```
+---+---+---+------------+
|  a|  b|  c|        d  |
+---+---+---+------------+
|  A|  A|123|   [A, B].  |
|  B|  B|123|[C, A, E, D]|
+---+---+---+------------+
```

this may be a bit similar to [How to aggregate values into collection after groupBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202997/how-to-aggregate-values-into-collection-after-groupby/34204640?noredirect=1#comment72878553_34204640) or the example from `HighPerformanceSpark` of https://github.com/high-performance-spark/high-performance-spark-examples/blob/57a6267fb77fae5a90109bfd034ae9c18d2edf22/src/main/scala/com/high-performance-spark-examples/transformations/SmartAggregations.scala#L33-L43

Using the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val flatten = udf((xs: Seq[Seq[String]]) => xs.flatten.distinct)
val d = flatten(collect_list($"d")).alias("d")
df.groupBy($"a", $"b", $"c").agg(d).show
```

will produce the desired result, but I wonder if there are any possibilities to improve performance using the RDD API as outlined in the book. And would like to know how to formulate it using data set API.

Details about the execution for this minimal sample follow below:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 21
+- LocalLimit 21
   +- Aggregate [a#45, b#46, c#47], [a#45, b#46, c#47, UDF(collect_list(d#48, 0, 0)) AS d#82]
      +- LocalRelation [a#45, b#46, c#47, d#48]

== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 21
+- SortAggregate(key=[a#45, b#46, c#47], functions=[collect_list(d#48, 0, 0)], output=[a#45, b#46, c#47, d#82])
   +- *Sort [a#45 ASC NULLS FIRST, b#46 ASC NULLS FIRST, c#47 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#45, b#46, c#47, 200)
         +- LocalTableScan [a#45, b#46, c#47, d#48]
```

[image: SQL dag]
[image: stage DAG]

## edit

The problems of this operation are outlined very well https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#be-smart-about-groupbykey

## edit2

As you can see the DAG for the dataSet query suggested below is more complicated and instead of 0.4 seem to take 2 seconds.
[image: dag for answer 1]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df.groupByKey(foo => (foo.a, foo.b, foo.c)).
  reduceGroups{
     (foo1, foo2) => 
        foo1.copy(d = (foo1.d ++ foo2.d).distinct )
  }.map(_._2)
```

Comment: But wont this create a lot of unnecessary objects due to the immutable scala collections used in the reduceGroups?

Comment: Please see the edit above, your SQL DAG is a lot more complex / slower than the datafFame approach.

Comment: this solution tries to avoid shuffling duplicated data, if there's not much duplications within the same key it's probably not worth to do this

Comment: this solution should be faster than other that involves shuffling just with big datasets that contains lots of duplicated records in d field

Comment: I see. Will tryit 2morrow on some bigger data. Anyway, do you think RDD with reduceByKey would be a good option here i.e. quicker?

Comment: the problem with the RDD is that you won't get any optimization and the serialization will be slower, using groupByKey + reduceGroups is the alternative to reduceByKey in Dataset API

Comment: anyway, depending on your data, RDD reduceByKey could be faster than groupByKey if this involves shuffling a lot of duplicated data

Comment: Thanks. Still, why is the DAG of the dataSet so much more complicated than dataFrame? Is this due to the extra map operation where `f => (f.a, f.b, f.c)` are mapped?